# adding a view in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, constraints

I created UITableViewController, and made a tableView, on fullscreen, as default. Now I want to add some view on top(view height 1/2 of view, table view height 1/2 of view). And I cant do this in storyboard, even when I am trying to add or to see some runtime constraints I get nil.

```
    for constraint in view.constraints() {
        println(constraint)
    }
```

for real I found one solution - make view programmatically and offset table view, but it wont works I think. Any ideas or solutions about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `UITableViewController`, use a `UIViewController` and put a `UITableView` within it, talking up half the view, and then your other view can take up the other half.

You could also use ViewController embedding, if you have a strong requirement for the use of `UITableViewController` instead of `UITableView`, but in the end you do the same thing of having a `UIViewController` into which the `UITableViewController.view` winds up being embedded.